# How to find a occurrence of a word using grep in a case sensitive manner

Tags: linux, grep

I've a file, with below content in it.

`foo`, `FOO`, `Foo`, `FOo` and i want to search with the lines which matches with the `FOo`, ie the 4th word in my file.

How can i achieve it using grep ?

Comment: Can you please paste a good representation of your input file and what output you want to obtain ?

Comment: ... to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply do

```
grep "FOo" file
```

**grep** by default does a case sensitive search. It matches all the lines that will have FOo in it.

**Input:**

```
$ cat file
hello foo
meow Foo
bhow FOo
ding dong Foo
the last one FOO
```

**Output**:

```
$ grep FOo file
bhow FOo
```

TIP:
If you want to do case-insensitive search use `grep -i`